Events occuring in 2 seconds window
i need suggestions to solve this type of problem: i have a table with different signals that are triggered in different timestamps, i need to calculate the time difference between each events and all others to find events that occurs in a window of maximum 2 seconds.
This process has to be done for each event, so for each row, the final target is to filter events that occurs almost at the same time(2 seconds window).
For now i tried to group by with a window of 2 seconds but each window act independently from the others and this is a problem for me.
code for the window:
-- select count(*) from final as f
-- group by WINDOW(f.RegisteredTimestamp, "2 seconds", "2 seconds")
